# Rendering a function's result

Tags: reactjs

It's my first time posting here, so i hope i'll be clear enough.

I'm doing a fetch on an outside API, which gives me a list of objects with each a name and an url. For each of those objects, i need to do another fetch on the url given, to get all the informations i want to show on my page.
I tried several ways, like calling the second fetch (**getIndividualInfos**) with the first one, but i couldn't access the result from my render.
Now i'm trying to call the second fetch function from my render, but i have no idea how to show the result i'm getting...

Here's my code, thanks for taking time to read me!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const ContentListePoke = (props) => {
  const [ressource, setRessource] = useState("?limit=151");
  const [list, setList] = useState({
    count: 3,
    next: "/",
    previous: null,
    results: [
      { name: "bulbasaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/" },
      { name: "ivysaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/" },
      { name: "venusaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/" },
    ],
  });
  let i = 0;


  //get name and pokemon infos url from selected pokemon
  const getInfos = async (ressource) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${ressource}`
    );
    const result = await response.json();
    //console.log(result.results);
    // result.results.forEach((element) => {
    //   getIndividualInfos(result.results[i].url);
    //   i++;
    // });
    return result;
  };

  //get info from ONE pokemon
  const getIndividualInfos = async (pokeressource) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${pokeressource}`);
    const resultindividual = await response.json();
    console.log(resultindividual);
    return resultindividual;
  };

  const handleClick = (event, ressource) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setRessource(ressource);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ressource);
    getInfos(ressource).then((result) => setList(result));
  }, [ressource]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <Button
          variant="danger"
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "?limit=898")}
        >
          All
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="danger"
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "?limit=151")}
        >
          Kanto
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="danger"
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "?limit=100&offset=151")}
        >
          Johto
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="danger"
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "?limit=135&offset=251")}
        >
          Hoenn
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="danger"
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "?limit=107&offset=386")}
        >
          Sinnoh
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="danger"
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "?limit=156&offset=493")}
        >
          Unova
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="danger"
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "?limit=72&offset=649")}
        >
          Kalos
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="danger"
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "?limit=88&offset=721")}
        >
          Alola
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="danger"
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, "?limit=89&offset=809")}
        >
          Galar
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className="containercards">
        {list.results.map((element) => (
          <div className="cardpoke">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h4 className="card-title">
                <span>{getIndividualInfos(element.url).order}</span>
                {element.name}
              </h4>
              <p className="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ContentListePoke;
```

Comment: FYI, "information" is an [uncountable noun](https://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2010/11/09/information) (neither singular nor plural). For that reason, "informations" isn't a word, and therefore neither is "infos". :)

Comment: It's different in my native language, i probably mixed than up! Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate component e.g `<Pokemon />` in which you will pass `url` and `name` props. And in `useEffect(() => ..., [])` you will fetch individual info by `fetch` with `url` from props and render `name` and `order`